# Change line color of text field when focused using RadDataForm in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using telerik pro ui library in nativescript, I struggled in changing the bottom line color of text field when focused to be appropriate to design

I want to change the blue default color of line

The text field currently rendered as shown in the following image

[image]

The code of template view is

```
<GridLayout rows="100, *" row="1" class="m-x-10 m-t-75">
                <RadDataForm #loginFormElement [source]="loginForm" [isReadOnly]="isLoading" row="0" class="fa">

                    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="email" displayName="" hintText="example@gmail.com" imageResource="res://fa_user" required="true"
                        index="0">
                        <TKPropertyEditor class="fa" tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Email">
                            <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle labelHidden="true"  labelWidth="0"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                        </TKPropertyEditor>
                        <TKNonEmptyValidator tkEntityPropertyValidators errorMessage="البريد الالكتروني مطلوب"></TKNonEmptyValidator>
                        <TKEmailValidator tkEntityPropertyValidators errorMessage="البريد الالكتروني غير صحيح"></TKEmailValidator>
                    </TKEntityProperty>

                    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="password" displayName="&#xf023;" hintText="كلمة المرور" required="true" index="1">
                        <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Password">
                            <TKPropertyEditorStyle class="fa" tkPropertyEditorStyle labelHidden="false" labelTextSize="18" labelFontName="FontAwesome"
                                labelPosition="Left" labelWidth="30" labelTextColor="#999"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                        </TKPropertyEditor>
                        <TKNonEmptyValidator tkEntityPropertyValidators errorMessage="كلمة المرور مطلوبة"></TKNonEmptyValidator>
                    </TKEntityProperty>
                </RadDataForm>
                <Button class="form-submit-button bg-light-green m-y-25 m-l-5 m-r-5" [text]="'تسجيل دخول'" (tap)="onSigninButtonTap()" row="1"></Button>
            </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The blue color is default accent color for all Android input fields. You can go to:
**App_Resources -> Android -> values -> colors.xml** file and change **ns_accent** to your color. You have other colors you can customize as well.
At the moment I'm trying to figure it out how to change font color in raddataform input field.

Comment: you can style RadDataForm Editor as Follows `<TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="name"> <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"> <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle strokeColor="#00695c" strokeWidth="2" fillColor="#4db6ac" labelHidden="false" labelTextSize="18" ios:labelFontName="Times New Roman" android:labelFontName="sans-serif-light" labelFontStyle="Italic" labelPosition="Left" labelWidth="60" labelTextColor="#00695c"></TKPropertyEditorStyle> </TKPropertyEditor> </TKEntityProperty>`

Comment: Yes, I know. But none of the properties change input text color. I could change the background color, or label color but no input field text color. Am I missing something? Which param represent input text color? fill color is background, stroke suppose to be underline? It actually didn't change the color in my case.

Comment: I also struggled with the difficulties of styling RadDataForm editors so, finally I switched to normal TextField and style it with css instead of RadDataForm